# Tracking employees time in office query - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

attempting to write a query that will subtract the first entry time off the last entry time for a given day so I can see how many hours between their first and last action. I can easily do this by copying data into a python script that I have but I'm wondering if I can alter my query to easily show it?

```
Select req.CREATE_DATE FROM REQUESTS req
Inner join USERTABLE usr ON req.ID=usr.REQ_ID

WHERE usr.userID = 'EMPLOYEENAME'
ORDER BY req.CREATE_DATE DESC
;
```

Answer (score 0):

With as many info as you posted (as well as probable typo - first name and surname belong to `usertable`, not `requests`, right?), I'd say that something like this might do the job.

```
select trunc(req.create_date) datum,
       max(req.create_date) - min(req.create_date) diff_in_days,
       usr.first_name,
       usr.surname
from requests req join usertable usr on req.id = usr.req_id
where usr.user_id = 'EMPLOYEENAME'
group by usr.first_name,
         usr.surname,
         trunc(req.create_date)
order by trunc(req.create_date) desc;
```

Comment: I think I caused confusion with including the first and surname in my original post. I understand what your query is doing but it doesn't work in my use case. I have rewritten my original query to remove those. It now just has all actions by the user, the first and surname are irrelevant to the query.

Comment: I'd say that what you removed is irrelevant in this case. If query I posted doesn't work (I thought it would), please, post sample data so that we'd see what you have. Also, post desired result (based on that sample).

Comment: Ahh your WHERE statement had an underscore in it which was causing issues. I have it running now but the DIFF_IN_DAYS result is shown as 0. I will try and fix it myself by making it DIFF_IN_HOURS :)

Comment: The DATUM field is showing as 25/02/21 00:00:00 - I think it is removing the HH MM SS